# php shell_exec() android command is not working

Tags: php, android, shell-exec

I am trying to run `shell_exec()` php function by android parameters.
I installed java and android SDK. They are working on terminal.
but it's not working on php.

For example:

```
shell_exec('android list targets');
```

Comment: where is php code running ?

Comment: in my computer on the lamp server.

Comment: your ph code call to adb command yet ? Similar this: shell_exec("adb devices");

Comment: no,your command is not working.

Comment: oh. so if you have not add adb path to envirenment path then you must call to absolute path of adb as: shell_excute("c:/android_sdk/platform-tools/abd.exe   devices"); //ex for windows

Comment: Might be easier to write a batch script (if on Windows) or shell script (if on Linux/BSD).

Comment: I am using a mint linux,when i am using this code shell_exec('ant debug'); its works very well but android commands doesn't work.